# Wordpress slug "pages" conflicts and results in error 404

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to have the following url structure on my wordpress site:

```
/pages
/pages/terms-of-service
/pages/workplace-policy
```

I have a page with the slug "pages". I have the page with the slug "terms-of-service" that's a child of the first one.

Yet when I go to `/pages/terms-of-service`, wordpress gives me a 404. What's interesting is that if I rename the first page's slug to `page` or `pagez`, it works. Making another e.g. `page2` the parent, also works and the route `/pages2/terms-of-service` gives me code 200 OK. There is something specific to the slug `pages` that's causing the issue, and I'm at a loss as to what it is.

I've clicked "save" in permalinks, which refreshes them.

My htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have verified no post_name in the database is "pages":

```
select distinct id, post_title, post_name from wp_posts 
  where post_name like '%page%'
  order by post_name asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your active theme or any active plugins, or any kind of customization is probably messing that up,

`pages` slug is not use anywhere by wordpress core function.

you can check the rewrite rule if there's anything that is using it.

Additionally, just set-up a wp fresh install locally, then create that page structure you have. Then copy your active theme on it.

Then add your active plugins one by one on that local install and see which one is causing that error.